# Django admin foreign key drop down field list only "test object"

Tags: django, django-admin

I have these two classes:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

class TestSubjectSet(models.Model):
    id =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
```

The TestSubjectSet form test list shows only string "test object".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to add `__unicode__(self)` or `__str__(self)` methods in your models class.

[http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.**unicode**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.__unicode__)

Comment: __unicode__(self) did not work for me but __str__(self) did . Am using django 11

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem. Adding

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.user
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you want to have different info returned from **str** function but Want to show some different info in the dropdown of admin. Then Above mentioned solution won't work.

You can do this by subclassing forms.ModelChoiceField like this.

```
class TestChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
 def label_from_instance(self, obj):
     return "Test: {}".format(obj.id)
```

You can then override `formfield_for_foreignkey`

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
  if db_field.name == 'test':
    return TestChoiceField(queryset=Test.objects.all())
  return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```